# Sales amounts of the top n selling vendors by month with other fields in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

i have a table in bigquery like this (260000 rows):

```
vendor  date                  item_price    discount_price
x       2021-07-08 23:41:10   451,5         0  
y       2021-06-14 10:22:10   41,7          0
z       2020-01-03 13:41:12   74            4
s       2020-04-12 01:14:58   88            12
....
```

exactly what I want is to group this data by month and find the sum of the sales of only the top 20 vendors in that month. Expected output:

```
month     vendor_name(top20)  sum_of_vendor's_sales  sum_of_vendor's_discount   item_count(sold)
2020-01   x1                  10857                  250                        150
2020-01   x2                  9685                   410                        50
2020-01   x3                  3574                   140                        45
....
2021 01   x20                 700                    15                         20

2020-02   y1                  7421                   280                        120
2020-02   y2                  6500                   250                        40
2020-02   y3                  4500                   200                        70
.....
2020-02   y20                 900                    70                         30
```

i tried this ([source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69861592/17334324)). But The desired output could not be obtained.

```
select month, 
  (select sum(sum) from t.top_20_vendors) as sum_of_only_top20_vendor_sales
from (
  select 
    format_datetime('%Y%m', date) month, 
    approx_top_sum(vendor, item_price, 20) top_20_vendors,count(item_price) as count_of_items,sum(discount_price)
  from my_table
  group by month
) t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  format_datetime('%Y%m', date) month, 
  vendor as vendor_name_top20, 
  sum(item_price) as sum_of_vendor_sales,
  sum(discount_price) as sum_of_vendor_discount,
  count(*) as item_count_sold
from your_table
group by vendor, month
qualify row_number() over(partition by month order by sum_of_vendor_sales desc) <= 20
```

Comment: it is works. Thank you.